# Pusher App events not triggering

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket

I'm testing out the Pusher library for handling websockets with a rather simple app using PHP and Javscript (jQuery) you can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JyVvr/1/

Tha backend `ajax.php` file contains this:

```
require 'lib/Pusher.php';

$message = $_POST['msg'];

$pusher = PusherInstance::get_pusher(); // My API key, secret, etc is directly set in the Pusher.php file

$pusher->trigger(
    'test_channel',
    'new_comment',
    array('message' => $message)
);

echo json_encode(array('message' => $message));
```

Basically the app just takes a message and appends it to the `ul` element on form submit, the appending part works just fine but the `new_comment` event isn't triggering so the app isn't working as intended, I used an alert just to test if it showed but it just does nothing plus it doesn't throw any errors or anything. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Pusher Debug Console](http://pusher.com/docs/debugging) for your app. If you don't see your event triggered in there then it's either not reaching or is not being accepted by the Pusher REST API.

There aren't any [issued raised](https://github.com/squeeks/Pusher-PHP/issues) about this Pusher PHP library.

Comment: That's VERY strange, I just tried today without changing anything in my code and it works fine, could it be that their server went down or my connection was too slow something like that?

Comment: We've not had any reported downtime. See: http://status.pusher.com. Give me a shout (phil@pusher.com) if you see any further problems and I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks, it must have been something else I'm not sure yesterday it didn't work but today it's fixed oh well really nice library btw!

Answer (score 2):

If the events aren't reaching Pusher, make sure the Pusher server time and your server time match or are within 599s of each other. I've been trying to figure this out recently and this article was the first one to appear, so just mentioning this for others to save them some time and headache.